# Delphi IdFTP Timeout

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Hi I use to IdFtp for image upload to server.My code is uploaded an image but after upload IDFTP does not disconnect.I cant find why im taking this result.
My code is

```
 Tfrm_main.fotoYolla(d:Timage;fileName:String);
    var
      Params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
      Response: TStringStream;
      var ms:TMemoryStream;

    begin


    ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      d.Bitmap.Resize(300,400);

      d.Bitmap.SaveToStream(ms);
     with IdFTP1 do
      try
       Host := 'myserver';
        Username :='anonymous';
        Password :='1234';
        Port:=21;
        Connect;

        Ms.Position := 0;
        Put(Ms, fileName);
      finally
        Disconnect;
      end;
    finally
      ms.Free;
      d.Free;
    end;
    ShowMessage('İmage is updated.');
    end;
```

After this code i taking 'Read Time Out' message.

Comment: Try to use `passive` mode

Comment: Ok.That is correctçThank you @valex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@valex write to true step on comment at my questions post.Its

```
passive:=true;
```

I added this code and finely work.Thank you